# ModuleNotFoundError and Pyenv and python 3.8.10

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyenv

I am working under Windows 10, and I have several version of python, but I need to work under Python 3.8.10 (with pyenv shell 3.8.10 check the picture below).

I get this exception when I launch my code:

**Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named '*statsmodels*'**

However, *statsmodels* has already been installed with pip (under the 3.10.8 MS version).
Indeed, it works under 3.10.8 but not under 3.8.10.

So I have activated venv i.e.  with this command *..venv\Scripts\activate*, and I install again inside this virtual environnement.

Indeed, now I see *statsmodels* under *c:\my_project_folder.venv\include\lib\site-packages*

I have set $PYHTONPATH="path to the project folder" through system properties/advanced/emvironement variables

[image: pyenv different version]

***Someone has an idea how to fix this exception ?***

Answer (score 2):

> However, statsmodels has already been installed with pip (under the 3.10.8 MS version). Indeed, it works under 3.10.8 but not under 3.8.10.

Different versions of python have different site-packages. When you choose the 3.8.10, python interpreter cannot get the packages that you installed in the 3.10.8's site-packages.

So the solution is to install the package again in your **python 3.8.10** :

1. Choose the Python 3.8.10 interpreter as you do in the picture
2. Use the command `pip install statsmodels` in the cmd to install this package to 3.8.10's site-packages.